# LTSpice to Autodesk EAGLE

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, eaglecad, ltspice

I have drawn a resistive network for test some detector components. It works well. So I want to proceed that project to further and create my own real circuit. 
After that EAGLE is the answer where I design PCB of my circuits. Now here is my target, I want to export schematics from LTSpice to importing EAGLE and after a couple edit to finishing this.

But after a few searching, I couldn't figured out how I can make it possible. Everybody has an LTSpice button on EAGLE's toolbar. I haven't. 
I'm using Autodesk Eagle 8.2.2 Premium version. There's nothing beside of the design link button.

Comment: Every button in Eagle has a command line analogue.  Hit the manual to find it

Comment: Of course i have searched before asking about that in here. I have looked at Help > General window and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two ways to do this in eagle.

In your schematic editor like you said, there's the LTC Spice button. If it doesn't appear for you, right click the top bar and make sure 'Command Texts' is ticked.

[image]

If this doesn't work or you don't have that option, then you can run the ULP manually.

Go to 'File' and select 'Run ULP'. Scroll down until you find the 'LTSpice.ulp' and run this instead. The button on the taskbar is essentially a shortcut to this .ulp file

[image]

Edit: As I was last aware this feature only works for Windows. They were working on OSX and Linux being able to import from LTSPICE but I'm not sure if they ever finished it.

Comment: Thanks for participation, Doodle. 
But there is no LTSpice.ulp in that directory. Now guess, I miss to say that my OS is Linux Ubuntu. Is that matter ?

Comment: Yes it is important, please see my edit

Comment: I'm not going to become complicate it. I will work on Windows. Thanks a lot again.